# How can i get current street location showing on Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I want my Website users to be showing their current street location on Google Map.
Just like "Facebook Check In" do. (It shows my current location on the map.)
How can it be done simply?

Answer (score 2):

You can show the current location of user on the basis of their IP address.
Use the following script:

```
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It returns XML data and retrieve the lat long :

```
var Latitude = latlng.lat();
var Longitude = latlng.lng();
```

and I think you will show marker on the basis of that.

Comment: Seems coool, Aryan. But i have 2 questions: (1) Will it be working on Mobiles ? ... and (2) Is there any Google Official Javascript rather then your link ?

Comment: yes, it will work on mobile and till date i have not found no any google official javascript link.

well it will work fine.

Comment: But on Mobiles, it showing the location of ISP. Not real current location of Mobile. :(

Answer (score 1):

According to http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Geolocation you can use the following code as part of initializing your map:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  browserSupportFlag = true;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  }, function() {
    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
  });
}
```

It uses the [W3C Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html), which is part of HTML5.